# Is there a way to work around using a break statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, break, binary-search

I have a working binary search function that asks a to user input a name and it will search for it in the Student array structure and display the corresponding average GPA for that student. It will keep looping for the user to enter in a name to search for unless the user enters in a period.

The problem I have is the `break` statement I am using. The requirements for this function that I need to follow does not allow me to use a `break` statement.

However, if I remove the `break` statement, my binary search will infinitely print out the output statement and will not work properly anymore.

Is there a way for me to work around this and not use a `break` statement? I have a feeling I could be using several `if` statements instead of the `break` statement.

```
void binarySearch(Student* ptr, int MAXSIZE)
{
   string target;
   string period = ".";

   int first = 0,
   last = MAXSIZE - 1,
   mid;

  do
  {
    cout << "Enter student name (Enter . to stop): ";
    cin  >> target;

    while (first <= last)
    {
        mid = (first + last) / 2;
        if (ptr[mid].name.compare(target) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Student " << target << " :gpa " << ptr[mid].avg << endl;
            first = 0;
            last = MAXSIZE - 1;
            break; // I am stuck on making the binary search work without using this break statement
        }
        else if (ptr[mid].name.compare(target) < 0)
            last = mid - 1;
        else
            first = mid + 1;
    }
    if (first > last && target.compare(period) != 0)
    {
        cout << "This student was not found. Enter another name" << endl;
        first = 0;
        last = MAXSIZE - 1;
    }
  } while (target.compare(period) != 0);
}
```

Comment: You should make sure the code you post has a consistent and logical indentation to make the code more readable (most of the `do` body is missing an indent level).

Comment: @crashmstr I will edit it right now. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark Already edited for you.

Comment: @J.Titus Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why? Are you in college? That's the only place you will encounter break-o-phobia. Out here in the real world we use it all the time. Somebody ought to tell them. You're probably expected to foul up your code with additional Boolean variables.

Comment: @EJP You are correct. My professor never wants us to use `break` unless it is for a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a `bool` into your loop!

```
bool nameFound = false;
while (first <= last && !nameFound)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (ptr[mid].name.compare(target) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Student " << target << " :gpa " << ptr[mid].avg << endl;
        first = 0;
        last = MAXSIZE - 1;
        nameFound= true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have just tried it and it seems to be working partially. It only works for the first search. When I enter in another name to search for, the output `cout` statement never shows up and what happens next is `Enter student name (Enter . to stop):` shows up on the screen. As I enter in another student name, it just keeps asking to enter in another student name.

Comment: Did you put the `bool` above the `do` loop per chance? You need to have it where I have shown: right above the `while` loop where it's used, but within the `do` loop

Comment: Silly me, wow I did not notice. I put it outside the entire `do` loop. Putting it where you have shown would reset it so that it can keep working right?

Comment: That's correct. If it was outside the `do` loop, once a single student was found, even if you entered a new name it wouldn't re-enter that `while` loop because `nameFound == true`; however, since it's within the `do while {}` scope, every time _that_ loop executes the `bool` is declared as `false` and your search will work.

Comment: Ok I got it now! Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: In general, `nameFound = true;` should be followed by `continue` to avoid inadvertently entering some of the later logic in the loop.  In this particular case it doesn't matter, but it makes your code more fragile as you might later add some more code to the bottom of the loop, not realizing that it will change the behaviour of something higher up in the loop.

Comment: I completely agree, and the only reason it's excluded here is because the OP _more-or-less_ specified that jump statements couldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `while` loop that you're `break`ing from in its own stand-alone function.

Now, `return;` will have the same effect as `break;`.

Comment: Yes that could work, however I am also not allowed to create any additional functions unfortunately.

Comment: @Mark I have other ideas, but no way to know if you would respond to them with "I am also not allowed to do that".  :)

Answer (score 0):

here's a work around I thought

```
do{

int ctr = 0;

while (first <= 0 && ctr ==0)
  {
   if (ptr[mid].name.compare(target) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Student " << target << " :gpa " << ptr[mid].avg << endl;
        first = 0;
        last = MAXSIZE - 1;
        ctr = 1 ;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: right my bad. and only saw your solution after I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stylistic comment (since the actual answer has already been posted): it is more reliable if you set up your necessary work variables right before they are needed, instead of relying on the various exit situations to reset them for a future iteration. Ie:

```
....
cin  >> target;

// Define and initialize right before they are needed.
int first = 0;
int last = MAXSIZE - 1;

while (first <= last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2; // Not needed outside the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to replace `break` with `goto`, and introduce a label after the `while` , e.g.:

```
do { 
   // ... 
   goto pointless;
   // ...
} while (bla);

pointless: ;
```

*Note:* This is worse than using `break;` in all respects other than complying to your stated requirement of not using `break`.